# How to use VF page as iFrame on a page outside of salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, iframe, web-to-case

I should use VF page as iFrame on a page outside of salesforce (web-to-case) like:

```
<iframe src="https://name.cs110.force.com/vfPageName"/>
```

But my page doesn't display.

What else should i do? (maybe in setup settings of orgs or somewhere else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called out in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_external_iframe.htm).

> In Setup, search for Session Settings. Under Clickjack Protection, select Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages either **with headers disabled** or **with standard headers**. Both these options allow framing on whitelisted external domains and provide clickjack protection.
>
> Then under Whitelisted Domains for Visualforce Inline Frames, add the trusted external domains where you allow framing. Ensure that your domain names meet format requirements.

Also, make sure the page is enabled for access. In your Sites setup menu, click on the domain you're using, scroll down to Site Visualforce Pages, and add your page to the list.